# Is it possible to reutilize a JSF page that uses a ViewScoped bean inside a dialog?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, jsf-2.2

I have a JSF page which works with a ViewScoped managed bean, that page requires an viewParam which is passed from URL.

I'm using Primefaces 4.0, and I want to know if there's a way to use that xhtml page inside a p:dialog and then pass some param to it.

From where I want to summon that dialog is a different page with a different bean, ViewScoped too.

My dialog actually looks like this:

```
    <p:dialog widgetVar="w_dialogAgregarInfo">
        <h:form id="dialogAgregarInfo">
            <p:tabView id="tabView">   
                <c:forEach items="#{iniciarProcesoController.mfuncionesAsociadas}" var="mFuncion" varStatus="loop1">      
                    <p:tab id="t_funcion_#{loop1.index}" title="#{mFuncion.nombre}" titleStyle="font-size:15px;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal">
                        <f:subview id="tab_#{loop1.index}">
                            <o:massAttribute target="javax.faces.component.UIInput" name="disabled" value="#{mFuncion.soloLectura}">
                                <p:panelGrid id="pg_funcion_#{loop1.index}" style="margin: 0 auto; box-shadow: none; width: 100%">
                                    <ui:include src="#{mFuncion.paginaFuncion}"></ui:include>
                                </p:panelGrid>
                            </o:massAttribute>
                        </f:subview>
                    </p:tab>
                </c:forEach>
            </p:tabView>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
```

And I'm calling this dialog as I usually do: just tell it to show.

```
<p:commandButton value="Agregar información" oncomplete="w_dialogAgregarInfo.show()"/>
```

But it show empty, pretty sure that I need to initialize the dialog's controller somehow, but I have no idea how to achieve that, any help would be apreciated, Thanks!!

Comment: How are you calling this p:dialog?

Comment: Added that to the question. I'm calling it when a button is clicked, just show it.

Comment: Not sure why you mention ViewScoped, the dialog has all the same contexts as the view. It's part of the same view. Maybe you just need `update=":dialogAgregarInfo"` in the button that opens the dialog. Dialog Framework is probably not needed here, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26507691/1341535.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [DialogFramework](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/df/basic.xhtml)

It allows you to call any xhtml by using something like :

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("anyPage", options, params);
```

where "anyPage" match your "anyPage.xhtml" page name, options are a set of properties given to the dialog. It takes a `Map<String,Object>` like the following:

```
Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<>();
options.put("modal", "true");
options.put("draggable", "false");
options.put("resizable", "false");
options.put("position", "top");
options.put("dynamic", "true");
options.put("appendTo", "@(body)");
```

And params are the parameters that the page receives, it takes a `Map<String, List<String>> params = new HashMap<>();`

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
values.add("exampleValue");
params.put("exampleParam", values);
```

Comment: Is this available in primefaces 4.0?

Comment: Ok that looks pretty cool, but how do I pass parameters to the page? Does that initialize the managed bean?

Comment: I don't use Primefaces anymore but I remember it works like another page, but it's in an iFrame

Answer (score 2):

*How do I pass parameters to DialogFramework?*

Create a map with your parameters:

```
      Map<String, List<String>> params = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
        values.add("value1");
        values.add("value3");
        params.put("paramKEy", values);
```

Then call

```
  RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("yourxhtmlpath", options, params);
```

Here is one nice example, [primefaces dialog framework.](http://lauraliparulo.altervista.org/primefaces-dialog-framework-how-to-make-it-work/)

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your bean class to have the same funcionality with another bean name.